# How to use jquery in a webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have a simple video player app created mainly using jquery , now I am bundling my js codes using webpack 4

By using google and stack overflow on how to use jquery with webpack here is my configurations

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var copyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const bundleOutputDir = './dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    return [{
        entry: './resources/views/pages/settings/bundle.js',
        plugins: [
            // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*']) for < v2 versions of CleanWebpackPlugin
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery'
              }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
             title: 'Output Management',
             title: 'Caching',
            })
        ],
        output: {

            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),      
        },
        externals: {
            jquery: 'jQuery'
          },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: bundleOutputDir
        },
        plugins: isDevBuild
            ? [new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin(), new copyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'demo/' }])]
            : [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()],
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.html$/i, use: 'html-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                    use: [
                      {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                { test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader' + (isDevBuild ? '' : '?minimize')] },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/i, exclude: /node_modules/, use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [['@babel/env', {
                                'targets': {
                                    'browsers': ['ie 6', 'safari 7']
                                }
                            }]]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // Exposes jQuery for use outside Webpack build
                    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'jQuery'
                    }, {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: '$'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    }];
};
```

Note : I have installed jquery and saved using npm

But unfortunatelly I am getting the following error

```
main.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:6)
    at e (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at e (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bundle.js:1
```

What is wrong with my configurations?

Comment: include your javascript file that is calling the jquery

Comment: Thisis the result in a bundled js

Comment: I get that, but seeing the code it's based on might help us see how you're setting it up to be built by webpack